# How create a Two way service function angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await, rxjs

I have a service for alerts that comunicates work components whit an alert component that displays a pop-up.
I work that whit `EventEmitters` like that:

**alert.service.ts**

```js
export class AlertService {
  @Output() alert: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

  sendAlertCont(data: any) {
        this.getAlert.emit(data)
    }
}
```

So, in any component I call the service function to activate the alert component

**any.component.ts**

```
export class AnyComponent {

constructor(private _alert: AlertService){}

clickedFunction(){
   this._alert.sendAlertCont('You don't have permissions')
}
```

**alert.component.ts**

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _alert: AlertService){}

ngOnInit(){
   this._alert.alert.subscribe(data => {
        this.alerta = data
        $('app-alert').fadeToggle()
    })
}
```

**The question is:**

How can I do the service function called `sendAlertCont()` returns a response sendig options in the `data` and getting the response in the component that sent the alert:

**AnyComponent**: send Data => **AlertService**: active Alert => **AlertComponent**: show alert & options

and then

**AlertComponent**: Send Response => **AlertService**: get & send response => **AnyComponent**: recives response

but all in the same function. Is posible?

I was thinking somethig like a Observable, Promise o Async Function like:

1. `this._alert.sendAlertCont('You don't have permissions').then(...)`
2. `var res = await this._alert.sendAlertCont('You don't have permissions')`
3. `this._alert.sendAlertCont('You don't have permissions').suscribe(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**alert.service.ts**

```
export class AlertService {
  showAlert$ = new Subject<string>();
  responeAlert$ = new Subject<string>();

  alert(alert: string): Observable<any> {
    this.showAlert$.next(alert);
    return this.responeAlert$;
  }
}
```

**any.component.ts**

```
export class AnyComponent  {
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }

  alert(): void {
    this.alertService.alert('You don\'t have permissions').subscribe((result) => {
      this.alertResult = result;
    });
  }
}
```

**alert.component.ts**

```
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.alertService.showAlert$.subscribe(alert => {
      // code for displaying this component
    })
  }

  close(result: string): void {
    this.alertService.responeAlert$.next(result);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-with-observable-func)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `BehaviorSubject` to communicate between components and services. Your `AlertService` could be something like this:

```
  alert = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  alertResponse = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  sendAlert(message: string) {
    this.alert.next(message);
  }

  sendResponse(message: string) {
    this.alertResponse.next(message);
  }
```

Then in the `AnyComponent` you can send the alert:

```
  sendAlert() {
    this.alertService.sendAlert("You don't have permissions.");
  }
```

In the `AlertComponent` show the alert message and wait for user's acknowledgement:

```
  alertMessage: string;

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {
    this.alertService.alert.subscribe(res => this.alertMessage = res);
  }

  reply(message: string) {
    this.alertService.sendResponse(message);
  }
```

And again in the `AnyComponent` subscribe and show the user's response from the AlertComponent:

```
  alertResponse: string;

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {
    this.alertService.alertResponse.subscribe(res => this.alertResponse = res);
  }
```

Check the Stackblitz I made based on your requirement: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opqhj4

Comment: So much thanks, but I was awnsering if is posible make it whit the same function... so you use two functions and now I have a solution in my proyecto like that (in two functions)... I hope you make me understand